# Touchscreen boundry

Tags: linux, touch-screen

My laptop is having touchscreen. When I connect an external monitor to it via USB-C, then touchscreen calibration of laptop get distorted. Note that this external monitor DO NOT have touchscreen.
It looks like system thinks that whole display is having touchscreen.
If I run `xinput_calibrator` then it expands on both the monitor.

Is there any way to setup touchscreen for said display only without running `xinput_calibrator --geometry` option?

Underlying system is customized. Hence expecting pure command-line non-interactive solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:

`xinput map-to-output <device_name> <monitor>`

e.g.
`xinput list` will give the list of connected device.

```
xinput map-to-output "ELAN238E:00 04F3:2A3B" eDP
```